# How do I avoid an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to input a number, and have the program create a new array of that length. I will then input all the elements in the array one at a time. After that I type a single number, and the program will search the array for that number. Unfortunately, the code I wrote below throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. How can I fix this?

```
import java.io.*;
public class aw
{
    public static void main(String args [])throws IOException``
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int z;
        boolean vince = false;
        System.out.print("Enter Element :");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        int [] jes = new int[a];

        for(z=0; z<jes.length; z++)
        {
            System.out.print("Numbers :");
            jes[z] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        }

        System.out.print("Enter search:");

        int []x = new int [100];
        x[100] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        if(jes[z] == x[100])
        {
            vince = true;
            if(vince == true)
            {
                System.out.print("Array "+jes[z]+ "Found at Index"+z); // here is my problem if i input numbers here it will out of bounds
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`

Comment: On what line is does the exception occur?

Comment: in my last line sir . i put a comment here - [CoderShei]

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with your code, 'cause there are several issues with this code... Not only with this `x[100] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());` which actually gives you the error.

Comment: actually itried to x[100] because i though if i use int x = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()); is the cause of ArrayIndexOutOfBounce so i try x[100] but it didnt work .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is that you reused z without resetting it.  Your loop increments z until it is greater than the maximum index of your array `jes`, so when you try to reuse z, you are using an index out of range.  I think you are missing a for loop when you are trying to compare the read in value with `jes` which could potentially reset and reuse z, but it might be clearer to use a different variable to increment.

The second is that you declared an array of size 100 for x, and are trying to access the 101st index (which is out of bounds).  `int[] x = new int[100]` has the indicies 0-99.

This code should work as you intended:

```
import java.io.*;
public class aw
{
    public static void main(String args []) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        boolean vince = false;
        System.out.print("Enter Element :");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        int [] jes = new int[a];

        for(int i=0; i<jes.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Numbers :");
             jes[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        }

        System.out.print("Enter search:");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        for(int i=0; i < jes.length; i++) {
            if(jes[i] == x) {
                vince = true;
                break; //found the value, no need to keep iterating
            }
        }

        if(vince == true) {
            System.out.print("Array "+jes[i]+ "Found at Index"+i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my first search is only integer that handle int x = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()); but i though it is the cause of array out of bounce so i changed it into int[] x = new int [100] .

Comment: If you are just searching for a number, you shouldn't have to put it into an array at all. @CoderShei I've edited that part out as it was unnecessary.

Comment: i see sir i will draft my x into a integer not an array . thanks a lot sir godbless :) !

Comment: You don't need the `[100]` in the line `if(jes[i] == x[100]) {`.

Comment: @CoderShei If this answers you question, you should click the checkmark next to this answer.

Comment: @turbo yes sir i already change it into == x only hehe . yes it work well thanks alot :)

Comment: @RyanCarlson yes sir i already checked it 100checked :) hehe .

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but you get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException when you try to access x[100]. x in that context is an array of 100 elements, but in java x[0] is the first element, so the last element of x is x[99], and x[100] is the 101th element... which is out of bounds!

Comment: the problem is if i input 3 elements and it will appear input 3 arrays so let say i input 2 , 4 , 6. then my array is {2,4,6} right ? and the next will ask what is your search number and if i search example 2 the output is ArrayIndexOutOfBounce instead of array 2 is found at index 0 [:3]

Comment: Alright, so if I understand correctly, here's what you want: first the user writes the length of the array (3), then he writes the elements of the array (2, 4, 6), then he writes the element he's looking for (2) and the app then says "element 2 found at index 0". Did I get that right?